# getting from now to till mid night PST time in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

my date time should be in the format that can print date like 2016-08-28T23:59:00-07:00

The server is in PST time zone. The calling code at 10:31PM PST on Aug 7th prints the ISO date as: 2016-08-08T05:26:49.687Z

The requirement is to get the two date values. first of whatever should be the equivalent PST value in the required format. and second should be until midnight of that day.

Comment: Hi Vik!  Have you looked into [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: A couple of things: 1. What research have you done, what attempt to solve the problem? 2. Abbreviations like "PST" are not standard; do you mean Pacific Standard Time (GMT-8)? 3. If so, note that places that are in PST in winter are on Pacific *Daylight* Time at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If by PST you mean Pacific Standard Time, it's GMT-8. (Note that places that are in PST in winter are on Pacific *Daylight* Time [PDT] at the moment, which is GMT-7.)

So to do this, you:

1. Get the current time in GMT.
2. Convert to Pacific Standard|Daylight Time (whichever you actually need) by subtracting 8 or 7 hours.
3. Determine how long it is from then until midnight, which you can do in several different ways. For instance, convert the time you have into seconds-since-midnight (e.g., `((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60 + seconds`) and subtract that from 86400, then convert what you have back into hours, minutes, and seconds.